# window.open agregando estilos al momento de imprimir

Tags: javascript

Tengo una página en `HTML` de prueba y dentro de ella un botón el cual activa una función para que la página pueda imprimirse.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al momento de imprimir respete mis estilos `css` en la página?

Este es el código del botón:

```
<div id="Imprimeme">Este es un div.<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <p id="Estilo">Parrafo</p>
</div>
<a onclick="javascript:Imprime('Imprimeme');" class="btn btn-primary">Imprime</a>
```

La función `imprime` es la siguiente:

```
function Imprime(Imprimeme){
            var c, tmp;
            c = document.getElementById(Imprimeme);
            tmp = window.open('','Impresion');
            tmp.document.open();
            tmp.document.write('<head><link href="css/print.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print"/></head>');
            tmp.document.write(c.innerHTML);
            tmp.document.close();
            tmp.print();
            tmp.close();
        }
```

Y este es el `CSS`, no tengo mas que lo siguiente:

```
@media print {
    #Estilo{
      font-size: 100px;
    }
}
```

*Captura de pantalla:*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer el `print` desde una nueva ventana, tendrías que mandar el *CSS inline* en el *HTML*. Otra opción es imprimir directamente en la misma página, por ejemplo:

```js
function Imprime(Imprimeme){
    window.print()
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title></title>
   <style media="print">
       #Estilo{
         font-size: 100px;
       }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="Imprimeme">Este es un div.<br/>
      <p id="Estilo">Parrafo</p>
   </div>
   <a onclick="javascript:Imprime('Imprimeme');" class="btn btn-primary">Imprime</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, anibalajt, y [bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta... Me sirvió de mucho, ahora si yo quisiera imprimir solo una sección de una página tengo entendido que para ello se utiliza el window.open digamos que en el ejemplo que puse quisiera imprimir el contenido de la etiqueta <p> es por ello que también lo estaba manejando con window.open ya que en el botón yo puedo especificar que sección quisiera imprimir para que la función a recibir identifique el elemento y lo muestre en la vista previa, y antes de mostrar la vista previa yo quisiera darle estilos con css

Comment: para hacer que se imprima solo una sección de la pagina puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera, te comparto un codepen https://codepen.io/anibalajt/pen/YZvmPd

Comment: Exacto, es lo que buscaba... muchas gracias anibalajt, es de gran aporte